# How to run process in terminal with reading only permission for given directory

Tags: linux, macos, shell, permissions, terminal

I am trying to run a process in my terminal but I don't trust the application that much.

Is there is a way to run that application with just read permission from selected directory?

I am using macOS.

Comment: you could run it in a `chroot` and as an unprivileged user. this should be pretty save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As knittl told, you can use `chroot` for making `jail`.

For the more complex things, MAC have MAC, (mean OS X have Mandatory Access Control), what allow specify what processes can do and what cannot. This implemented with the `sandbox` mechanism, what is extremely powerful and fine grained.

you need setup the sandbox, so:

- man sandbox
- man sandbox-exec

but these are unfortunately not very helpful ;(

Basically, you need setup a profile for the sandbox. Example profiles are in the /usr/share/sandbox/*.

The best what you can do, google for "os x sandbox".

As i told above - here is no good docs, probably because it is currently not in final stage. :( You can experiment with it (especially with the debug mode). Anyway, these links should help a bit:

- https://www.romab.com/ironsuite/SBPL.html
- http://blog.0x0lab.org/2010/03/macosx-sandbox/

Your case is simple enough (IMHO), so will be enough enable the exec-process for your program, enable read and deny write to regex "/*" (everywhere). Maybe, deny network.

I'm not a sanbox expert, so **YOU** must experiment - but try to the start with something like:

```
(version 1)
(debug deny)
(allow default)
(allow process*)
(deny network*)

(allow file-read-data file-read-metadata (regex "^/.*"))
(deny file-write* (regex "^/.*"))    
(import "bsd.sb")
```

so, allow execute programs, deny networking, allow read and deny write... TEST first!

Comment: that is sound great ... Can you provide me with a link to tutorial about because I searched and I did not find good one ...